# Excel VBA Copy Sheet/Line

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have 2 Master Sheets based on 2 conditions of location. I import this data from an Excel Workbook into a worksheet on the Master Sheet Workbook. I think it would be better if I was able to scan the first column (A for example) and if the row meets a certain condition it would move the entire row to the respective Master Sheet just below the current data. If it meets condition B it goes to the other master sheet. I can then use Remove Duplicates in Excel to filter the data. My current code is below and I am fairly new to VB Automation. Any ideas on what kind of code I could use to select and move the rows based on criteria into 2 seperate master worksheets?

```
Sub Copy_DataCDN()
Sheets("CDNDataDump").Range("A2:AC10000").Copy _
Sheets("CDN").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Sheets("CDN").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, this can be done by looping through the cells in your condition column (in the example code it's column A).

Here's the example code for you to modify.

```
Sub MoveToSheets()
    Dim dataSource As Worksheet: Set dataSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim dataTargetA As Worksheet: Set dataTargetA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim dataTargetB As Worksheet: Set dataTargetB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    Dim dataSourceRange As Range: Set dataSourceRange = dataSource _
    .Range("A1:A" & dataSource.Cells(dataSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each Cell In dataSourceRange
        'Test 1 - I'm checking if the cell value is a number as an example.
        If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) = True Then
            dataTargetA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value _
            = Cell.EntireRow.Value
        'Test 2 - Checking if the cell value is "e".
        ElseIf Cell.Value = "e" Then
            dataTargetB.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value _
            = Cell.EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In the `For Each Cell In dataSourceRange` loop you can have as many conditions as you need. You could have more sheets to paste to as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly and the loop is a great idea and much more compact than what I thought it would be! Thank you :)